# как открыть ссылку c#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio

подскажи такой вопрос, есть папки с ссылками на сайты, как мне её распарсить и перенести в wpf или windows form как кнопки, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку он открывал файл который взял из указанной папки ? или хотя натолкните на мыслить как это можно реализовать ?

Comment: В `WinForms` для ссылок есть `LinkLabel`  
В WPF гиперссылки  https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/UI_WPF/level24/24_3.php

Comment: Вам в `WinForms` или в `WPF`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В WinForms можно так:
Создадим метод, который возвращает Url из файла ссылки:

```
private string GetUrl(string fileName)
{
    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        return null;
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)?.Where(r => r.ToLower().Replace(" ", "").StartsWith("url=")).FirstOrDefault()?.Split('=');
    if (lines != null && lines.Count() > 0)
        return lines[1];
    else
        return null;
}
```

Создадим метод, который создает Button с методом BtnClick:

```
private void createButton(string caption, string url)
{
    Button newButton = new Button();
    newButton.Text = caption;
    newButton.Tag = url;
    newButton.Click += btnClick;
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(newButton);            
}
private void btnClick(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    var url = (sender as Button).Tag.ToString();
    Process.Start(url);
}
```

А теперь по клику на буттон:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\abc");
    int i = 1;
    foreach(FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
    {
        if (fi.Extension == ".url")
        {
            var url = GetUrl(fi.FullName);
            var caption = string.Format("link{0}", i);                    
            createButton(caption, url);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

В принципе, можно обойтись и без метода GetUrl и открывать прямо файлы, а не содержащиеся в них ссылки:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\abc");
    int i = 1;
    foreach(FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
    {
        if (fi.Extension == ".url")
        {
            var url = fi.FullName;
            var caption = string.Format("link{0}", i);                    
            createButton(caption, url);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```